# Updating nextjs from 8 to 9.3.3 broke styling

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I just updated nextjs from 8 to 9.3.3, and some of my styling broke.

Previously I was importing `.scss` files and they were locally scoped to their respective components.

After updating to 9.3.3, it seems that components with `classNames` that are named the same are now sharing styles, so that leads me to believe that something with the sass-loader or css-loader in `next.config.js` seems off.

this is my `next.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const envConfig = dotenv.config();

const config = withSass({
    cssModules       : true,
    cssLoaderOptions : {
        modules       : true,
        sourceMap     : true,
        importLoaders : 1,
    },
    sassLoaderOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './')], //eslint-disable-line
    },

    useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,

    webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders }) => { // eslint-disable-line
        const ENV = {};

        for (let entry in envConfig.parsed) {
            ENV[`process.env.${entry}`] = JSON.stringify(envConfig.parsed[entry]);
        }

        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(ENV));

        return config;
    },
});

module.exports = config;
```

#### What I've tried

I've changing my config around like this:

```js
const config = withSass({
    cssModules       : true,
    cssLoaderOptions : {
        modules       : {
            mode: 'local',
            exportGlobals: true,
            localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
            context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), //eslint-disable-line
            hashPrefix: 'my-custom-hash',
        },
        sourceMap     : true,
        importLoaders : 1,
    },
    sassLoaderOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './')], //eslint-disable-line
    },

    useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,

    webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders }) => { // eslint-disable-line
        const ENV = {};

        for (let entry in envConfig.parsed) {
            ENV[`process.env.${entry}`] = JSON.stringify(envConfig.parsed[entry]);
        }

        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(ENV));

        return config;
    },
});

module.exports = config;
```

which didn't work.

My last resort which **does** work is manually going into each `.scss` file and changing them to `x.module.scss`, which would take a lot of time going into each file. Is there something wrong with my config?

Comment: Does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app/60944296#60944296 ?

Comment: Next.js now has built-in sass support. That might be causing a problem. https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#built-in-sass-support-for-global-stylesheets