# How to use Sass and Css on Next Js

Tags: css, sass, next.js, css-loader

I've been trying to use sass and css modules in my next.config.js, but keep running into this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@riskalyze/react-ui/node_modules/@riskalyze/calendar/assets/index.css
Unknown word (1:1)

> 1 | var api = require("!../../../../../../style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
    | ^
  2 |             var content = require("!!../../../../../../css-loader/index.js!./index.css");
  3 | 
  4 |             content = content.__esModule ? content.default : content;
```

After reading around on github and stackoverflow it sounds like its because I have two instances of css modules configurations in my next.config.js, but I'm unsure how to reduce that to one while still keeping this logic in tact:

```
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
      });
```

Below is my full next.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

const aliasPathsToResolve = [
  {
    name: 'react-ui',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/@riskalyze/react-ui/')
  },
  {
    name: '@babel/runtime-corejs2',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/')
  }
];

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass({
    cssModules: true,
    cssLoaderOptions: {
      importLoaders: 1,
      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    },
    webpack: (config, { defaultLoaders }) => {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: defaultLoaders.babel,
        include: /react-ui/
      });

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
      });

      aliasPathsToResolve.forEach(module => {
        config.resolve.alias[module.name] = module.path;
      });

      return config;
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app/60944296#60944296

Comment: NikolaiKiselev what if I have a bunch of scss files for each different component in the app?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Sass in Next.js project with built-in Sass support.

No configuration required, just install the Sass package:

```
npm i sass
```

Next.js will see this dependency and enable built-in Sass loader.

You can include global styles in `/pages/_app.js`.

For component or page specific Sass files you can use built-in support of CSS modules.

For example, if you have a component `Button.js` you can create a Sass file `button.module.scss` and include it in the component.

[Adding Component-Level CSS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css)