# How to implement a Next.js SVG Loader

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

since Zeit has a new brand, there are no updates for:

- @zeit/with-css
- @zeit/with-sass

My code was working and now I can't even run my website due to that problem. How can I load SVG differently? I tried using .babelrc but didn't work.

The code ***next.config.js***:

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass({
    webpack(config, options) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
          },
        },
      });
      return config;
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Next.js 9.3 you can use built-in CSS and SASS support.

See [Built-in SASS support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app/60944296#60944296) for more information.

As for `svg` - you don't need a loader for it.

Assuming you have `public/foo.svg` image you can specify it in CSS as `url(/foo.svg)`.

Comment: I have tried that and still not working. The error is:
https://prnt.sc/swjgm6

I have fixed it by adding .babelrc:
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["inline-react-svg"]
}

Comment: @LeonardoGrginčić, It seems you're importing the image (parsing with Webpack), in that case, yes, a loder is needed. Another way to do it is just to specify path to an image, so a browser would request and load it, without compiling it at build time.