# Cannot use global scss in Next.js , message Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, node-sass

I have installed node-sass in my next.js app, and trying to import my global scss file with import '../styles/style.scss'; in _app.js component, but I'm getting this error:

```
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages\_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages\index.js
```

I have no next.config.js file.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you had any luck cause I happen to have encountered a similar issue. I actually get the exact same error despite importing global styles only in pages/_app.js and using only CSS modules as stated in next.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903470/1334703

https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-remove-imports

This is a plugin for nextjs. The default behavior is to remove all `.less`/`.css`/`.scss`/`.sass`/`.styl` imports from all packages in `node_modules`.

```js
// next.config.js
const removeImports = require('next-remove-imports')({
  test: /node_modules([\s\S]*?)\.(tsx|ts|js|mjs|jsx)$/,
  matchImports: "\\.(less|css|scss|sass|styl)$"
});

module.exports = removeImports({
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message is very clear, global styles must be imported in `_app.js`

Try it with the official documents
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support