# How to solve problem with "Global CSS cannot be imported" in nextjs app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I try to use your library in NextJS app but I accuse following error:

```
./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm
Location: node_modules/react-fullpage-accordion/dist/full-page-accordion.js
```

I imported all like your example is written

```
import { FullpageAccordion, Panel } from 'react-fullpage-accordion';
import "react-fullpage-accordion/dist/react-fullpage-accordion.css";
```

Update.

I renamed react-fullpage-accordion.css to react-fullpage-accordion.module.css, and then try to importem as well.
Error still occur.

```
./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm
Location: node_modules/react-fullpage-accordion/dist/full-page-accordion.js
```

think error is made by this following code

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports["default"] = void 0;

var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));

var _propTypes = _interopRequireDefault(require("prop-types"));

require("normalize.css");

var _panelContext = require("./panel-context");

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { "default": obj }; }

/* eslint-disable react/forbid-prop-types, no-unused-vars, import/no-unresolved, import/extensions */
var FullpageAccordion = function FullpageAccordion(_ref) {
  var children = _ref.children,
      height = _ref.height;
  return /*#__PURE__*/_react["default"].createElement(_panelContext.PanelContextProvider, null, /*#__PURE__*/_react["default"].createElement("div", {
    className: "panels",
    "data-testid": "panels",
    style: {
      height: height || '100vh'
    }
  }, children));
};

FullpageAccordion.defaultProps = {
  height: undefined
};
FullpageAccordion.propTypes = {
  children: _propTypes["default"].node.isRequired,
  height: _propTypes["default"].string
};
var _default = FullpageAccordion;
exports["default"] = _default;
```

but I am afraid of changing something in third part code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app)

Comment: Nope, I did all the say: change names of files, have sass, remove next.config.js..