# Unable to load css file in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs and using Nextjs, I want to include/add CSS to my project, My CSS files exist in `styles` folder, To include this I created the file `_document.js` and used the following code, but CSS file not loading, Where I am wrong? Here is my `_document.js` code

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="../styles/css/style.css"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to include CSS? Why use @import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036977/best-way-to-include-css-why-use-import)

Comment: Global CSS should be imported in `_app`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet and [Next.js Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app).

Answer (score 1):

To import CSS in your React, you can use `JS`'s import.

Add

```
import "../styles/css/style.css";
```

at the beginning of your file.

So, it will look like this:

```js
import "../styles/css/style.css";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to use this in _document.js not index or app.jsx

Comment: Yes, it works the same way.

Comment: i am getting error "CSS cannot be imported within pages/_document.js. Please move global styles to pages/_app.js.
Location: pages\_document.js"

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app can answer to this error in more detail than I can.