# Where to add external CSS link in a specific page in Next.js applications?

Tags: next.js

I have an external CSS file, and I want to add it to a specific page in next.js, but when I try to add it like this:

myPage.js

```
        <Head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lala.css" />
        </Head>
```

Next.js complain with a warning saying that we shouldn't add external CSS in the head, and they recommend adding this Link in the custom document file `_document.js`([this is from their documentaion](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-stylesheets-in-head-component)).

The problem with this solution is that this external CSS link will be global for every page! I want to add it to `myPage.js` only.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a css file and import it inside your page (using standard: import "./file.css").

In this css file, you can use the @import rule:

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lala.css");
```

Just tried it with bootstrap, and it is working fine. More about @import css rule here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Comment: Now I get this Error `Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).`

Comment: I tried to add `.module` to the CSS file name, but the error disappear and the external CSS file doesn't load.

Comment: I am using NextJS 13 with experimental app directory. So things are maybe different here :| Maybe take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app and try to update your css file name to file.module.scss

Comment: Also, check that the css file isn't cached (hard reload), you may see things appears

Comment: I tried changing the file name to file.module.scss, the external file is not loaded (or maybe it loaded but next.js is changing the class names? ), Propaply there is no way to do it.

Comment: is this the only way?
before the app dir in nextjs, i could import it in the head of the _document file