# Why does next.js force using modular CSS instead of a linked stylesheet per page?

Tags: css, next.js

I'm trying to add a link stylesheet that's been minified using `sass:watch` and importing it into a specific page of next.js (13), but when I add it using the head component got this warning:

> Do not add stylesheets using next/head

I don't want to use modular CSS or Sass because they've been added to head using `<style>` tag and not been cached if I'm not wrong, so how?

[related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75938635/where-to-add-external-css-link-in-a-specific-page-in-next-js-applications)

Answer (score 0):

The Next.js documentation actually gives a nice clear explanation of why it doesn't like stylesheets in the head, and a possible way to fix it:

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-stylesheets-in-head-component

Comment: thanks for your time, but my question was how can i have style per page without being worry about next js warning and also without modular.css, pointing to something abvious like its doc wont help me and others

Answer (score 0):

As i figured it out and didn't pay attention to it before, every modular css|scss after build convert to css files, so using modular css not be added to head tag like in development mode, so we can use it like external style sheet per page