# Nextjs | Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, sass

I try use this app

```
https://github.com/imranhsayed/woo-next/tree/master/src/styles
```

when I uncomments tyls in pages/_app.js then working, but how to correct import styles? Because in _app.js

is:

```
import "../src/styles/style.scss";
import "../src/styles/main.scss";
```

and this crash application:

```
./styles/main.scss
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages\_app.js
```

Comment: Maybe its: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941853/next-js-global-css-cannot-be-imported-from-files-other-than-your-custom-app?rq=2